# Need to remove None from the list

Tags: python, excel

I have excel having column names in the first row. I need to read it without `None`:

```
a = [Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Value]
[((u'Step', u'Test Case ID', u'Traceability  Ref', u'Test Description', u'Display', u'Test conditions', None, None, None, None, None, u'Test Criteria', u'Delay Time(ms)', u'Capture Time(ms)', u'Automation Type(A/S)', u'Expected Output', None, None, None, u'Actual Output', u'Comments'),)]
```

I tired using filter:

```
a = filter(None, a)
```

I need to remove the `None` (which is the empty column in my excel).

Comment: `filter(None, a)` is actually pretty close. It'd remove empty strings, zeros, and other falsy values, though. Are you on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: You tried using `filter`... and what happened? did it work?

Answer (score 10):

The problem with your solution is your list itself. If you look closely, it is not a list of values which you could filter, but a list, with a single tuple which single element is another tuple which then contains all your values.

So if you fix your list `a`, then it will work

```
a = [Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Value]
a = list(filter(None, a[0][0]))
```

Or in short:

```
a = list(filter(None, Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Value[0]))
```

Comment: Or perhaps just `a = list(filter(None, Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Value[0]))` for less garbage; the outermost wrapper is coming from the `[...]` construct.

Comment: In general case, you rarely want to use filter(None, ...), as it filters out elements evaluating to `False`, such as `None`, `0`, `[]`, `''`. A list comprehension `[col_name for col_name in Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Value[0] if col_name is not None]`  might be an alternative.

Comment: a = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Value[0]))

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while None in a:
    a.remove(None)
```

Comment: This is **much slower** equivalent of `filter(lambda x: x is not None, a)`, which is what OP already tried to use.

Comment: To be fair, I did try it... on my phone using SL4A. I had spotty 4G so I couldn't look up the `filter` documentation (which I rarely use).

Comment: The problem is, that this _would_ work if it were a plain list with some `None`s in it (and in this case, `filter(None, a)` would work just as well and much faster), except _it is not_, as explained in the other answer.